# Tel ou tel vs tel et tel

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

What is the difference between **tel ou tel** and **tel et tel**?
What is the proper way to convey them in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that *tel ou tel* is the singular and *tel et tel* is the plural. *Tel ou tel X* and *tel et tel X* both convey that there are many possible X and it is not known which one(s) will get picked. *Tel ou tel X* is used when a single X is in play, *tel et tel X* is used when multiple X will be in play together.

English has a similar construction with *this or that* vs *this and that* (and a mostly-synonym phrase *such-and-such* (*so-and-so* for people) which can be either singular or plural).